# How do I tell which machine is the Certificate Authority?

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, ad-certificate-services

We have a network using Windows Server 2003 with Active Directory. A few years ago I set up the Certificate Authority on one of the servers. Recently I wanted to do some maintenance, but found that the CA on that machine hasn't been issuing certificates since 2007, and yet users on the network are getting Auto-enrolled certificates all the time, so SOMETHING must be issuing them.

How do I tell which machine is the active CA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CertUtil.exe will give you most of the information you want. There's a very good blog posting by Tony Murray [on his blog here](http://www.open-a-socket.com/index.php/category/certificate-authority/) about using Certutil and querying the AD for the info you want.

Answer (score 0):

Examine one of those certificates and have a look at who issued it.

Comment: Doesn't help. The "issuer" is my own username, or the username of whoever the certificate belongs to. It doesn't say which hostname the CA was from.

Comment: That's not correct. The certificate should contain the path to the issuing CA(s). Guess something strange is happening here...